# How to replace only first appearance of HTML tag pair?

Tags: jquery, regex

My string:

```
<h2>headline</h2>
<p>content</p>
<h2>another headline</h2>
<p>another content</p>
```

I want to replace only the first headline `<h2>headline</h2>` with another string.

So far I have `str.replace(/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/, 'another String')` but that replaces `<h2>headline</h2><p>content</p><h2>another headline</h2>` because of the second `</h2>`.
Is there a way to only replace the first `<h2>(.*)<\/h2>`?

Something like: `str.replace(/<h2>(.*[except <\/h2>])<\/h2>/, 'another String')`

Comment: Is this intentionally tagged as jQuery or did you mean JavaScript. You make no use of jQuery in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery solution will goes like :

```
e = $j("<div>" + string );
e.find("h2").first().html("any html you want");
e.html()
```

JS solution will goes like

```
d = document.createElement ("div");
d.innerHTML = string;
d.querySelector("h2").innerHTML = "any html you want";
d.innerHTML
```

or simple string operations

```
var x = string ;
x.substr(0,x.indexOf("<h2>")+4) + "you string " +  x.substr(x.indexOf("</h2>")+5)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:first` pseudo selector to change the content of first `h2` like following.

```
$('h2:first').text('another string')
```

If you want replace the `h2` itself then use `replaceWith()` method like following.

```
 $('h2:first').replaceWith('another string')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex:

```
str.replace(/<h2>(.*?)<\/h2>/, 'another String')
```

Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible,

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. No jQuery, just native JavaScript.

```js
var s = '<h2>headline</h2><p>content</p><h2>another headline</h2><p>another content</p>'

// Create a holder element and let the document parse our HTML
var el = document.createElement('div')
el.innerHTML = s

// Find and replace what we want
el.querySelectorAll('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'REPLACED'

// Just to output in our snippet
document.querySelectorAll('#init')[0].innerHTML = s
document.querySelectorAll('#res')[0].innerHTML = el.innerHTML
```

```css
div{border: 1px solid red}
```

```html
<h3>New HTML</h3>
<div id="res"></div>
<hr>
<h3>Original HTML</h3>
<div id="init"></div>
```

### Aside

It's generally a bad idea to use regular expressions for complex structures like HTML. You really want to parse them. That's the idea behind this answer is to leverage the browser (which knows how to parse HTML) to find the element your looking for and work with it.